# I'm really confused between THAN OTHERWISE and THE OTHER WAY AROUND

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, phrase-usage

my sentence is

> If you learn English while working, it would definitely take a lot of
> your time to complete the task than the other way around.

Or should I say

> If you learn English while working, it would definitely take a lot of
> your time to complete the task than otherwise.

In both sentences, I'm trying to say you should not learn English while working.

Comment: Neither text is syntactically valid - ***for so many reasons*** that this is practically Off Topic "proofreading". Personally, I think the basic *idea* here is bordering on nonsense ([***as any fule kno,***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Any_fule_kno), learning a language "on the job" is by far the most effective approach), so I can't see any easy way to convert it into idiomatically valid English anyway.

Comment: I think you mean 'it would take a lot _more_ time'. _The other way around_ would be working while learning English, which, as FF says, makes the sentence meaningless.